# Order BY will not work at all

Tags: mysql, sql

From the following table, how can I select the most recent record for each id, head and userId? This thing has driven me mad.

```
"id"    "head"  "type"  "updated"   "userId"    "addedDate"
"1"     "2"     "0"     "1"         "1"         "2013-11-23 21:09:23"
"1"     "2"     "1"     "1"         "1"         "2013-11-23 21:09:40"
"2"     "2"     "0"     "1"         "1"         "2013-11-23 21:09:44"
"2"     "2"     "1"     "0"         "1"         "2013-11-23 21:09:47"
```

**Failing Queries - Neither will return results as desired**

```
SELECT id, addedDate FROM test WHERE userId = 1 and head = 2 GROUP BY id HAVING MAX(addedDate);
SELECT id, addedDate FROM test WHERE userId = 1 and head = 2 GROUP BY id ORDER BY MAX(addedDate) DESC ;
```

**Current Incorrect Results**

```
"id"    "addedDate"
"2"     "2013-11-23 21:09:44" // Incorrect. This is the first one for it
"1"     "2013-11-23 21:09:23" // Incorrect. This is the first one for it
```

**Desired Results**

```
"id"    "addedDate"
"2"     "2013-11-23 21:09:47" // The one that was added last
"1"     "2013-11-23 21:09:40" // The one that was added last
```

**Edit**
The whole problem here is I dont want the max() in the select, becuase I'm using `PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR`

Comment: *All* columns in the output clause *must* either be in the GROUP BY or an aggregate. If not, then the *results will be unreliable*. Remove the GROUP BY and the sorting will "work", even if still not the desired output. (I blame MySQL for accepting such queries to begin with.)

Comment: (This problem is a special-case of [greatest-n-per-group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group), where n=1.)

Comment: @user2864740 So is the one by pepe or oerkelens ok to use?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, MAX(added_date) FROM test WHERE userId=1 AND head=2 Group By id
```

Comment: How can I achieve the same thing by leaving out the max(addedDate) in the select?

Answer (score 1):

To get your desired result, simply do this:

```
SELECT id, MAX(addedDate) 
  FROM test 
 WHERE userId = 1 
   AND head = 2 
 GROUP BY id
```

If you want a records where the addedDate is the max, you have to include that in your HAVING clause completely like so:

```
HAVING addedDate = MAX(addedDate)
```

But in this case that is not necessary.

If you want in one query all the latest date per is, userid and head, simply make it:

```
SELECT id, userId, head, MAX(addedDate) 
  FROM test 
 GROUP BY id, userId, head
```

optionally add

```
 ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: How can I achieve the same thing by leaving out the max(addedDate) in the select?

Comment: By complicating your query, depending on whether you want top use MAX anywahere else, or you want to get a TOP 1 per group. Why do you want to remove MAX from your SELECT clause? Is this a specific homework assignment?

Comment: I'm using PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR. So I need only id and addedDate. This isn't a homework assignment.

Comment: Just the results the way I've done in my question are ok. Come to think of it, I should have mentioned I did do it the way both of you did. When I removed the max in the select it would not work. So I asked.

Comment: `Fetch a two-column result into an array where the first column is a key and the second column is the value. Available since PHP 5.2.3.`
I don;t see why you couldn't use MAX(addedDate), what if you use `MAX(addedDate) AS AddedDate`? Then it has a simple column name. If not, it's more of a PHP than a SQL question